# Nested Control Flow in list comprehension Python

Tags: python, for-loop, nested, list-comprehension, control-flow

How can I convert this for loop into a list comprehension with a nested if statement?

```
stock = []
for i in range(10):
     if i <= 5:
         trade = "buy"
     elif i > 5 and i <= 7:
         trade = "hold"

         if i == 6:
             trade = "short-sell"

     else:
          trade = "sell"
     stock.append(trade.capitalize())
stock
```

['Buy',
 'Buy',
 'Buy',
 'Buy',
 'Buy',
 'Buy',
 'Short-sell',
 'Hold',
 'Sell',
 'Sell']

The best I've got so far is:

```
["Buy" if i <= 5 else  "Hold" if i > 5 and i <= 7  else "Sell"
 for i in range(10)]
```

['Buy', 'Buy', 'Buy', 'Buy', 'Buy', 'Buy', 'hold', 'hold', 'Sell', 'Sell']

Any help would be totally appreciated! :)

Comment: Remember that shorter is not always better.  The FOR/IF code might be easier to read, especially if at some point another programmer has to read it.

Comment: Good point, John, but generally, shorter code tends to be faster.

Comment: I fixed the error, it was just the stock.append(trade.capitalize()) was not indented properly.

Comment: **1** There's no need to have `if i == 6:` nested inside the `elif i > 5 and i <= 7:`. The code would be easier to read and more efficient if it simply had `elif i == 6:` ... `elif i == 7:` **2** Yes, a list comp is slightly faster than doing `.append` in a traditional `for` loop, but you probably save much more time by getting rid of that `.capitalize` call.

Comment: @MichaelRSF no, I would say that is not a very good generalization about shorter code being faster.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I do suspect there is a correlation. Code being both long and slow because it's written by bad coders, and code being both short and fast because it's written by good coders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the `i == 6` case. Try

```
["Buy" if i <= 5 else  "Short-sell" if i == 6 else "Hold" if  i <= 7  else "Sell" for i in range(10)]
```

this gives us

```
['Buy', 'Buy', 'Buy', 'Buy', 'Buy', 'Buy', 'Short-sell', 'Hold', 'Sell', 'Sell']
```

However, there's really no good reason to do it this way.  It's not easy to read and (as you saw) it's easy to overlook errors.  If I was you I would stick with your original pattern (The code you posted here doesn't quite work though)

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept that, but it's not the equivalent to a nested if statement, but rather another elif statement that isn't nested.

Comment: They are logically equivalent.  If you really want the nested `if` statement, you can use `('Short-sell' if i == 6 else 'Hold') if i > 5 and i <= 7`

Comment: That `i<=7` could be `i==7`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an equivalent expression to your various conditional statements:

```
['buy' if i <=5 else (('short-sell' if i == 6 else 'hold') if i > 5 and i <= 7 else 'sell') for i in range(10)]
```

In action:

```
In [10]: ['buy' if i <=5 else (('short-sell' if i == 6 else 'hold') if i > 5 and i <= 7 else 'sell') for i in range(10)]
Out[10]:
['buy',
 'buy',
 'buy',
 'buy',
 'buy',
 'buy',
 'short-sell',
 'hold',
 'sell',
 'sell']
```

Note, in this case, your nested `if` statement is equivalent to:

```
if i == 6:
    trade = "short-sell"
else:
    trade = "hold"
```

Note, don't use this rediculous, nested conditional expression. It's the sort of thing that would get you excoriated in a code review. Just use the for-loop. If you have a burning desire to use a comprehension, then put the conditional logic in a function using the full nested conditional statements, something like:

```
In [14]: def f(i):
    ...:      if i <= 5:
    ...:          trade = "buy"
    ...:      elif i > 5 and i <= 7:
    ...:          trade = "hold"
    ...:
    ...:          if i == 6:
    ...:              trade = "short-sell"
    ...:
    ...:      else:
    ...:           trade = "sell"
    ...:      return trade
    ...:

In [15]: [f(i) for i in range(10)]
Out[15]:
['buy',
 'buy',
 'buy',
 'buy',
 'buy',
 'buy',
 'short-sell',
 'hold',
 'sell',
 'sell']
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very different approach:

```
action_tests = [
    ('buy', lambda x: x <= 5),
    ('hold', lambda x: (5 < x <= 7) and (x != 6)),
    ('short-sell', lambda x: x == 6),
]

stock = [next((action for action, test in action_tests if test(i)), 'sell') for i in range(10)]
```

The "else" condition is handled by the default value of `next` in the case that none of the tests return true for your `action_tests`.

You really don't want to be squeezing all your complicated logic into a single line because it will make maintainability a nightmare - it will be hard to detect bugs, and even harder to add more logic down the line when the spec changes.

This approach is an improvement over the original set if `if` statements in that it is easily extendable... simply add new functions to the `action_tests` in the appropriate priority order and the comprehension still works!  Only a single line needs to be added when you want to add support for some new action down the road, rather than potentially having to rework your `if` branches.

Comment: Wow, that's really cool you only use one if statement. I really just wanted to see if there were any limitations to list comprehension so I could better understand it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do a list comprehension

```
>>> ["Buy"*(i<=5) + "hold"*(i == 7) + "short-sell"*(i == 6) + "sell"*(i > 7) for i in range(10)]
['Buy', 'Buy', 'Buy', 'Buy', 'Buy', 'Buy', 'short-sell', 'hold', 'sell', 'sell']
```